# How many Facebook Users can be retrieved in a single Graph API Query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the following request, it is possible to retrieve multiple Users with the Facebook Graph API:

`https://graph.facebook.com?ids=user1, user2, user3,...`

Does anyone know if there is a limit for the number of users I can retrieve in a single query?

Comment: What's the most you've tried? (and yes I'm 100% sure there is a limit)

Comment: If nothing else there's a limit as per the `GET` request maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how and through which servers you are passing the URL, there [could be a limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues) of 255, 1024 or 2083 characters to the maximum URL length. If one existed, this would be your limiting factor. If you're using javascript to make the query, you should probably assume a max length of 1024 characters or less.

Assume you're passing this via a server-side script with no limits on outbound URL length, I'd guess you'll find there is a Facebook limit. Facebook seems to like 5*10<sup>n</sup>-item limits their services. I'd suspect this one is probably the same, with n=1, 2, or 3.

Comment: That is the theorical limit, Michael is looking for the limit set by the api