# How to retrieve multiple user account details through their Facebook IDs in graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This could be a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275753/how-many-facebook-users-can-be-retrieved-in-a-single-graph-api-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275753/how-many-facebook-users-can-be-retrieved-in-a-single-graph-api-query?lq=1),  but can some one provide a complete working example for following.

I have set of different Facebook account Ids, and i need to get the respective account details(user name etc) from these account ids. I need to send a Batch Request for Graph API. Something as follows,

*(https://graph.facebook.com?ids=user1, user2, user3,...)*

Is this possible as pure HTTP GET request ?

I am using Facebook SDK with Android for the moment.  I have gone through the API doc but unable to build the required query yet. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe post a snippet of your code so we can try to solve your problem better. With the info you provided, the URL https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=user1,user2,user3 works just fine and returns 3 users.

The URL format looks correct. Keep in mind the total character limit, but otherwise I suspect you are stuck in a different place (e.g. sending the query or saving the result).

Comment: Hi Alex, this is the way how i tried [link] (http://graph.facebook.com/?ids={10204537543093774,12342232221})  Kindly mention the full request that you tested. Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hi, if you click on my link, you'll see that it actually works.
Here's another example: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=user1,user2,user3,681141984
The last ID is actually mine, so you can see that it works just fine with real requests too.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue, i used Graph API V2, and this is how i get the account id :           JSONObject fbObject = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
String fbID = fbObject.getString("id");
String email=fbObject.getString("email");     But when i noticed that i get different id from this way (http://findmyfacebookid.com/)   . Second approach works fine. Got any suggestions ?

Comment: It seems that the Graph object might have the info you're seeking anyway. Take a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user and you can see the attributes that you have access to. The ID that you're getting back is unique to your app and looks like it doesn't work with the query you want to use.

Comment: Hi , it should be, i will look into the reference. Thank you very much for your time and effort.